# I want my app to take the input as someone's twitter handle return the tweets over the last 1 week

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I want to be able to find the tweets a particular user has made in the last 7 days. Sample code as to how to accomplish this would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not believe Twitter exposes an endpoint to get only the number of tweets. You will have to fetch all the tweets for the period you are interested in, and then count them (or take the length of the array, or something along those lines).

I believe you can get the tweets you are looking for using the [statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) API endpoint.

Comment: how I do set the value to a week's worth of tweet?

Comment: Well that API returns 20 (by default, or changed with the count param) objects at a time, and each object is a Tweet object. Each Tweet object will contain a created_at attribute, which is the time is was created. Keep fetching tweets until then created_at time is before 1 week ago. You will also probably want to exclude alot of embedded objects, such as users, replies, etc.

Comment: wow. thanks. but do you have any sample code in your head that I could take a look that, something that will get me started in the right direction?

Comment: I do not, however there are example calls in Twitters docs and discussions. If you need more, you should be able to find examples by googling. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6340

Comment: @user2115365: Your best bet is to get some code sort of working and then ask for help with refining it.  The above from Nick is a good starting point and I would probably look at jquery $.get for actually performing the queries. Start with a hand crafted query, run it through jquery and get a feel for it, then build on that.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you would need to look at search/tweets in the API:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Comment: While this is an idea, I do not believe that tweets going back a week are all indexed and available in the search API. I believe it only goes back a few days, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Ah you're right. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search says 6-9 days, so it might just be not enough. And I guess it might change in the future.